# Caps lock button does nothing

Tags: windows-xp, keyboard, capslock

On my computer, the Caps Lock button no longer does anything.

Troubleshooting Steps:

- Swapped out several keyboards. Same problem with each.
- Tried virtual keyboard Caps Lock (does work, and even turns on the indicator light on the physical keyboard).
- Unplugged, replugged USB cables into different USB ports, and restarted. No change.
- Used Device Manager to check for driver updates. No updates found.
- Looked for USB / keyboard settings in BIOS to toggle. None found.

System Specs:

- Dell SK-8115 keyboard
- Windows XP Professional 5.1.2600 Service Pack 3 Build 2600
- Dell Optiplex 760

Comment: Use an app like SharpKeys to confirm that the key hasn't been remapped.

Comment: Hava you checked `Regional Settings>Keyboards and Languages`?

Answer (score 0):

Jeeped provides the [answer](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_xp-hardware/caps-lock-button-does-nothing/61bc6e35-5207-48ed-93fd-cc6e701167f5):

Delete `Scancode Map` in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layout`.